# Ionic 3 adding subscriptions for notification topic in a loop

Tags: ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

In my Ionic app, I am trying to dynamically subscribe to topics based on the user's preference. So every time the app loads I am trying to re-subscribe them to their topics. I noticed that without resubscribing them, my callback code is not executed, and thus no popup notification is generated, when a notification comes for that given topic. Rather, the notification just ends up in the notification drawer (android).
So, the app boots up, I request the list of sub topics from my db and loop over each one calling the below function to subscribe:

```
  addBillNotificationSubscription(topic: string){
    console.log("Adding a bill notification subscription for topic: " + topic)
    this.pushObject.subscribe(topic).then((res:any) =>{
      console.log("Received test channel notification for topic: " + topic)
      if (res.additionalData.foreground) {
        this.showNotificationPopup(res);
      }
    })
    console.log("Done Adding subscription")
  }
```

Now when I call this in a loop, only the first iteration ever gets executed.  I've double checked the elements in the list, there are several and even print them out in another loop right before the loop to subscribe.  I'm assuming that I'm completely not understanding some fundamental thing, but I'm stumped. There's not much documentation (that I've found) on the proper way to even do these topic subscriptions or example use cases.

I've fully tested one topic subscription and have gotten it working in case the question arises.